# javafx-2 ComboBox converter: method toString(T object) not called for null values

Tags: java, combobox, javafx-2

In a javafx2 application, a ComboBox should present a list of items, in the example they are `String` s for simplicity.

This list contains a `null` item, since i want the user to be allowed to make no choice.

Since I was playing with the converter property of the ComboBox, I wondered if I could use it to provide a nice representation for the no-choice case, for example "[none]" instead of an empty line.
But i've discovered that the toString(Object object) is never called for the null item.

Here follows the shortest code that reproduces the case. Version information included.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

public class T05 extends Application {
@Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.runtime.version"));
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("javafx.runtime.version"));
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("os.version"));
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("os.name"));        

    ComboBox c = new ComboBox();
    //c.setEditable(true);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(c));
    primaryStage.show();

    c.getItems().add("first");
    c.getItems().add(null);

    c.setConverter(new StringConverter<String>(){
        @Override public String toString(String object) {

            System.out.print("converting object: ");
            if (object==null) {
                System.out.println("null");
                return "[none]";
            }
            System.out.println(object.toString());
            return object.toString();
        }

        @Override public String fromString(String string) {
            throw new RuntimeException("not required for non editable ComboBox");
        }

    });

}

}
```

And here it's the output, as you can see the true branch of the `if (object==null)` statement is never called. Is it a bug or a feature, and is it yet possible to customize null representation?

```
 1.6.0_29-b11
 2.2.3-b05
 6.1
 Windows 7
 converting object: first
 converting object: first
 converting object: first
```

**update**
Adding a (just uncomment it):

```
c.setEditable(true);
```

I get another behavior, that is, clicking on the null item in the combo selection box, I get the method toString called, but the result is not presented in the selection box.

Answer (score 4):

you can use `setPromptText` method to display "[None]" in comboBox if user make no choice.

Sample Code :

```
comboBox.setValue(null);

comboBox.setPromptText("[None]");
```

Comment: +1: This seems to be a valid workaround in many cases. I've tested it and it works, but not when the comboBox is editable. To be precise: the prompt text is EVER displayed in the "selection box", but it is not displayed in the "text field area" when the combo is editable. However, I can't consider this a response to the original question since the question is about a possible bug. I've updated the question with further clues on a buggy behavior.